# .Net Core HttpClientFactory dispose de HttpClientHandler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Actualmente estoy configurando de esta manera mi httpclientfactory

```
   HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; }

        };

        serviceCollection.AddHttpClient("ignoreSSL", c =>
            {
            }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(h => httpClientHandler);
```

Esto lo hago para desactivar la validacion de certificados de seguridad, pero al hacer demasiados request recibo esta excepcion:

**Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'SocketsHttpHandler'.**

Actualmente construyo mi httpclient de esta manera

```
            HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("ignoreSSL");
```

Haciendo pruebas, esto se soluciona de esta manera sin httpclientfactory

```
            HttpClient ad = new HttpClient(handler, false);
```

Por mas que busco no encuentro como indicar a httpclientfactory que no haga dispose a mi handler?